Find a story about a man waking up alone in the world told by narrator on Youtube
I recall vividly watching a series of youtube videos about a man waking up in a world with no people. I cannot find any reference to it through google or ai chatbots or youtube search

It was told by a narrator
It was old. I think early YouTube.
The video was low resolution, possibly just still images.
He wakes up on the east coast of the US
All electronics have stopped functioning
He eventually meet a few other people
He starts traveling to find his family/wife/girlfriend
Some standard post apocalyptic themes


Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Are you asking us to identify the YouTube videos? That is off-topic for this site.  Or are you saying that the narrator in the YouTube videos was reading a short story or novel published earlier, and you want that work identified? In that case, the details about the actual story are too common in post-apocalyptic fiction to be distinctive enough for the story to be identified. Could you please edit your question to add more narrative details? Thanks.

I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be asking for identifying a series of YouTube videos, which is out of scope for this site. If OP means to ask about a novel or short story, the question should be edited accordingly.

@SilentSojourner Unfortunately, [movies.se] SE management decided to make identification requests off-topic (link), so this question couldn't be re-asked there.

Additionally, this question is very low on detail. Pretty much everything that you've described falls under "standard post apocalyptic themes", which means it's going to be hard to pin down a single correct answer based on that.

@verbose I figured maybe it was based on some form of written story as the videos were very bare bones. I did look for a forum more focused on video, but could not find one. The most unique part of it to me was how it was told though.

@Randal'Thor Is it standard for 99.9% of the population to disappear over night? Maybe it is haha
